# How to display multiple rows from database to multiple textbox?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

Data in 'lcAmount' in the database is '15' for 4 rows and I want to call it to multiple textbox per row.

Database:

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Sick leave unconsumed</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" id="sickLeave" name="sickLeave" class="form-control" <?php echo $sickUnconsumed; ?> />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Vacation uncomsumed</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" id="vacation" name="vacation" class="form-control" <? php echo $vacationUnconsumed ?>/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Maternity uncomsumed</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" id="inpUN" name="inpUN" class="form-control" <? php echo $maternityUnconsumed ?>/>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Emergency uncomsumed</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" id="inpUN" name="inpUN" class="form-control"  <? php echo $emergencyUnconsumed ?>/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller PHP

```
$query = "SELECT lcAmount FROM leavecounts WHERE accountID = ?";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $sickUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
         $vacationUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
         $maternityUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
         $emergencyUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
$query = "SELECT lcAmount FROM leavecounts WHERE accountID = ? and ltypeID =1";
$params1 = array($accID);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $query, $params1);
while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    $sickUnconsumed = $row1['lcAmount'];

}

$query1 = "SELECT lcAmount FROM leavecounts WHERE accountID = ? and ltypeID =2";
$params2 = array($accID);
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query1, $params2);
while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1)){

    $vacationUnconsumed = $row2['lcAmount'];


}
$query2 = "SELECT lcAmount FROM leavecounts WHERE accountID = ? and ltypeID =3";
$params3 = array($accID);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query2, $params3);
while($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2)){

    $maternityUnconsumed = $row3['lcAmount'];


}
$query3 = "SELECT lcAmount FROM leavecounts WHERE accountID = ? and ltypeID =4";
$params4 = array($accID);
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($con, $query3, $params4);
while($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3)){

    $emergencyUnconsumed = $row4['lcAmount'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This  will display multiple values for multiple textboxes you just have to take html in the loop **or you can copy the values returned by result set and store them in array and separate the html.**

```
 <?php

  $query = "SELECT lcAmount FROM leavecounts WHERE accountID = ?";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
       $sickUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
       $vacationUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
       $maternityUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];
       $emergencyUnconsumed = $row['lcAmount'];

  ?>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Sick leave unconsumed</label>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
         <input type="text" id="sickLeave" name="sickLeave" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($sickUnconsumed)) echo $sickUnconsumed; ?>" >
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Vacation uncomsumed</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" id="vacation" name="vacation" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($vacationUnconsumed)) echo $vacationUnconsumed; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Maternity uncomsumed</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" id="inpUN" name="inpUN" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($maternityUnconsumed)) echo $maternityUnconsumed; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Emergency uncomsumed</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     <input type="text" id="inpUN" name="inpUN" class="form-control"  value="<?php if(isset($emergencyUnconsumed)) echo $emergencyUnconsumed; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>

 <?php
 }//while 
 ?>
```